# Access transaction instructions from get_transaction_with_config()

Tags: rust, solana-sdk

I call the `get_transaction_with_config()` the following way:

```
let parsed_transaction = rpc_client.get_transaction_with_config(
    &Signature::from_str("{__SIGNATURE__}").unwrap(),
    RpcTransactionConfig {
        max_supported_transaction_version: Some(0),
        encoding: Some(UiTransactionEncoding::JsonParsed),
        commitment: Some(CommitmentConfig::confirmed()),
    }
);
```

Now I try to access the transaction instructions with:

```
println!("{:?}", parsed_transaction.transaction.transaction.message.instructions);
```

But I can not go deeper than `parsed_transaction.transaction.transaction`. Someone has an idea what do I do wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bit more nesting on the rust side if you want to get to the instructions. You'll need to do:

```
use solana_transaction_status::{EncodedTransaction, UiMessage, UiTransactionEncoding};

// and later...

              let tx = rpc_client.get_transaction(&signature, UiTransactionEncoding::JsonParsed).await.unwrap();
              match tx.transaction.transaction {
                  EncodedTransaction::Json(json) => {
                      match json.message {
                          UiMessage::Parsed(message) => {
                              let instructions = &message.instructions;
                              println!("{instructions:?}");
                          }
                          _ => panic!()
                      }
                  }
                  _ => panic!()
              }
```

You can walk through all of the types that come from `get_transaction`, starting at the function in the RPC client at https://docs.rs/solana-rpc-client/latest/solana_rpc_client/rpc_client/struct.RpcClient.html#method.get_transaction